# Обновление цвета у input type=color

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос такой - у нас есть 2 input'a color и я хочу, что бы цвет сразу передавался в background, когда человек водит и выбирает цвет в цветовой палитре. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.colors').addEventListener('input', function(ev) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right bottom, ${this.querySelector('input:first-child').value},${this.querySelector('input:last-child').value})`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"><input type="color"><input type="color"></div>
```